# How can i set session data to specific item from array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session

This is what I tried:

```
$id = mysql_query("SELECT userid from members where username='".$gebruikersnaam."'");    
$_SESSION["id"] = (string)$id;
var_dump($_SESSION)
```

With a result like this:

```
array[1] { ["id"]=> string(15) "Resource id #14"}
```

instead of the actual string value

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: to use the string variable in other pages

Comment: This looks [terrifyingly insecure](http://bobby-tables.com/). Are you **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mysql_query function returns a resource. You need to fetch a row from that resource. That will have the data you want in it.

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $unescapedUsername);
$result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT userid FROM `members` WHERE username = "' . $username . '"');
// ^ result is now a resource
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
// ^ row now has an array
$_SESSION['id'] = $row['userid'];
```

An as everyone has said, don't use mysql_* functions anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Use mysqli instead of mysql and avoid sql injections:

```
$res = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT userid from members where username='".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $gebruikersnaam)."'");    
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
$_SESSION["id"] = (string)$row["id"];
```